# Packets are not going to the correct interface?

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, network-interface

After my application injects a packet with `source 100.64.0.77` and `destination 192.168.1.95` into the virtual `utun2` interface, the packet is being forwarded to the `en0` interface and sent to it's destination as expected. However, when a response packet from `source 192.168.1.95` to `destination 100.64.0.77` is received, it is received on the `en0` interface.

How can I get this response packet to be received by the `utun2` so that my application is able to read this packet?

ifconfig for utun2:
`inet 100.64.0.77 --> 100.64.0.77 netmask 0xffffff00`

```
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Netif Expire
default            192.168.1.254      UGSc           en0       
default            link#10            UCSI         utun2       
100.64.0.77        100.64.0.77        UH           utun2       
127                127.0.0.1          UCS            lo0       
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH             lo0       
169.254            link#7             UCS            en0      !
192.168.1          link#7             UCS            en0      !
192.168.1          link#10            UCSI         utun2       
192.168.1.92/32    link#7             UCS            en0      !
192.168.1.99       8c:a9:82:2e:d6:2e  UHLWI          en0    986
192.168.1.254/32   link#7             UCS            en0      !
192.168.1.254      70:f1:96:86:e6:a0  UHLWIir        en0   1196
224.0.0/4          link#7             UmCS           en0      !
224.0.0/4          link#10            UmCSI        utun2       
224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWI         en0       
255.255.255.255/32 link#7             UCS            en0      !
255.255.255.255/32 link#10            UCSI         utun2
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks all right to me. If you're using source NAT from TUN to en0 you need to use the NAT table for the reverse path as well. Without NAT, the packet just needs to be forwarded.

Comment: I am not using source NAT. How can I just forward the packet from en0 to tun? What do I need to do? Currently, what I think is happening that the packet is sent to the OS networking stack and sees that the destination IP address is `192.168.1.95`. It then knows that it meant to go to `en0` (and it does do this). However, when a packet is destined to `100.64.0.77` it just arrives at `en0`.